# Trying to write a mod rewrite to make my dynamic url user friendly but not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a news page that feeds a detail page with an id which in turn queries that database using id received to get results. I am trying to make the normal url e.g:

```
xyz.com/news-detail.php?nrf=23
```

to something more friendly like:

```
xyz.com/news/the-title-of-the-news/
```

On my news page, the link to the news article is like:

```
<a href="news-detail.php?nrf=<?php echo $row_news['ntitle']; ?>"><?php echo $row_news['ntitle']; ?></a>
```

and on the news-detail page, i have

```
 $newstitl = "";
    if (isset($_GET['nrf'])) {
      $newstitl = $_GET['nrf'];
    }

    $query_news = "SELECT newsID, ntitle, ndetail, nphoto, nauthor, ndate FROM news WHERE ntitle='$newstitl'";
    $result_news = mysqli_query($connJackie, $query_news);
    $row_news = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_news);
    $totalRows_news = mysqli_num_rows($result_news);
```

which i believe is supposed to get the record from the database based on the title.
The problem is, its not working.The url shows like

```
xyz.com/news-detail.php?nrf=the%20title%20of%20the%20news
```

I am quite new to mod-rewrite, but trying to improve my dynamic links to more friendly ones. I have read various articles on mod rewrite and that's how i tried to do this. 
My rewrite rule in the .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\_\\-]+)/?$ news-detail.php?nrf=$2 [NC,L]
```

I have also tried this but it also did not work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([\w-]+)/$    /news-detail.php?nrf=$1 [NC,L]
```

Any help in correcting and explaining would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: The reason you're getting: `the%20title%20of%20the%20news` is because you're printing spaces in a url. Spaces in url's will be encoded into `%20`. What you should do is to create another column called something like "slug" where you "slugify" the title (replacing spaces with dashes etc. There are libraries for this) and use _that_ value when you search for the record in your db. That's the most common way of doing it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well, for the form that enters data to the database, i am using prepared statements. Since there are no user inputs for this, thats why i used it the way it is. But that can be amended. As regards slugifying the titles, i can get that done. But my interest is if the rewrite code is done properly. Cause i expected to have something like `xyz.com/new/the-title-of-the-news/` but i still get the `news-detail.php?nrf=` which should not be.

Comment: What is the URL you're using? The rewrite code simply takes the url `/news/something` and _internally_ sends it to the url `new-detail.php?nrf=$1`. If the later is the link the user uses, that's what the user is going to see. Not really getting the issue.

Comment: You're putting the  `$_GET` param directly into your query. `$_GET`-params are user input. Thus, you're wide open to sql injections. If you're already using prepared statements in other places, use it everywhere.

Comment: @anubhava Resulted to a 404 error page. Object not found

Comment: @anubhava `http://localhost/news/the title of the news` That should be fine but its not loading the page with that info from database. Thinking if its the query part now that has the issue.

Comment: Now change rule to this: `RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ news-detail.php?nrf=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava Still the same 404 error

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for your help. I will continue to look into it hopefully i'ld would find what's wrong.

Comment: First make sure your htaccess is enabled and working.